# Need help combining columns from 2 tables and keep remaining data in rows based on parameters in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-express, intersect

I am needing some help with this! I have been steered toward the intersect function, but it seems limited as it only matches and returns matched values. I am trying to combine 2 tables on a common column value and return the rows based on a date parameter. Is this even possible using SQL? Thanks in advance!

My starting tables look like this:

```
name             date       doc          info
janedoe          7/21       jones        47
jonwall          7/1        nick         21


name             date       doc          info
janedoe          6/21       jones        74
jonwall          8/31       hall         22
```

I want to combine these rows by duplicate name. And keep the remaining data based on most recent date. so the end result should look like this.

```
name             date          doc          info
janedoe          7/21          jones         47
jonwall          8/31          hall          22
```

Is there anyway anyone could help me on this???? I am currently using SQLExpress

Comment: "janedoe" <> "jane doe".

Comment: thank you. names are pre-concatenated!

Comment: If you are keeping that data from the most recent date wouldn't jonwall's doc be hall and info** be 22?

Comment: yes. Sorry I made a change at last minute to highlight why i wanted to combine, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH allRows AS (
     SELECT * FROM tableA
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT * FROM tableB
), mostRecent AS (
     SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
              (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC) as rn
     FROM allRows
)
SELECT *
FROM mostRecent 
WHERE rn = 1
```

You should have some `ID` column, otherwise you are risking having two person with same name.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked flawlessly! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: You will have to explain what you mean. And probably better if open a new question. You can link this question if that help to explain your new question.

Comment: If I wanted to add another parameter if the first parameter were the same how would I go about doing that. I have a tried a couple of things but it seems to keep erroring out! So for example if the date was the same (eg: both were 7/1) and i wanted the second parameter to be location (not in the example but needed for real use) There are only two locations. So if I wanted "blocation" to be the decider i could.

Comment: Again, I need an example to understand the problem. This doesnt have parameters. You have to describe your problem complete. Please  do the effort and explain the problem with sample data and expected output.

Comment: I have created another question and linked this one to that question to better illustrate my issue. I am sorry i did not notate that. Thank you for all of your help!