# Need help adding a second parameter to a combine list.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wanting to add a second parameter if the first parameter fails/same date. I want location to be the second parameter and this case "location a". So in this instance:

```
name             date       doc          info           location
=====================================================================
janedoe          7/21       jones        47                   a
jonwall          7/1        nick         21                   a

name            date      doc          info          location
=================================================================
janedoe          7/21       jones        74                  b
jonwall          8/31       hall         22                  b
```

the ending should appear like this

```
name             date          doc          info           location
=========================================================================
janedoe          7/21          jones         47                 a
jonwall          8/31          hall          22                 b
```

[Need help combining columns from 2 tables and keep remaining data in rows based on parameters in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442337/need-help-combining-columns-from-2-tables-and-keep-remaining-data-in-rows-based/45442441?noredirect=1#comment77896325_45442441)

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the question. It is hard to backtrack and provide an answer to your question through a pointer back to the original question. You should provide a complete question. However, I will take a stab. Using the query that was the answer to your previous answer, you need to add the `location desc` or `location asc` to the windowing function's partition to act as a tiebreaker when two dates match.

Also, take a look at the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) command. It provides a much cleaner approach to similar problems.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(name NVARCHAR(20),date DATETIME,doc NVARCHAR(20),info NVARCHAR(20),location NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @B TABLE(name NVARCHAR(20),date DATETIME,doc NVARCHAR(20),info NVARCHAR(20),location NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @A SELECT 'janedoe','7/21/2017','jones','47','a'
INSERT INTO @A SELECT 'jonwall','7/1/2017','nick','21','a'
INSERT INTO @B SELECT 'janedoe','7/21/2017','jones','74','b'
INSERT INTO @B SELECT 'jonwall','8/31/2017','hall','22','b'

INSERT INTO @B SELECT 'janedoe','7/21/2017','jones','74','a'
INSERT INTO @B SELECT 'jonwall','8/31/2017','hall','22','c'

    ;WITH allRows AS (
         SELECT * FROM @A
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT * FROM @B
    ), mostRecent AS (
         SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                  (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC, location desc) as rn
         FROM allRows
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM mostRecent 
    WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: looking to the data I think is `location ASC`, but seem ok for OP request.